# Angular 2 - ASP.NET MVC app - NO SPA

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

With Angular 1 I could define my app in the body like this: `<body ng-app="myapp">` Then I could load different controllers in different views within my MVC app.

Let's say in Home/Index view I will load one controller and and Home/About i could load a different one and do different logic.

I am trying to understand Angular 2 and I have a feeling that all you can do with it is a SPA?? Are you kidding me? If I don't want to build a SPA basically I have to duplicate my code and create angular app again and again for each view. Is this true that you have to build only SPAs?

How can I use Angular 2 on top of my MVC app, using all MVC functionalities like routing, etc.?

Comment: You are definitely using Angular in the wrong way. Angular (1 and 2) are SPA Frameworks and should be just used for that. Angular apps require quite much of dependencies to be loaded/rendered on a per request basis. Most of these full-fledged JS Frameworks (like Angular, React, even ASP.NET (Core) MVC) are very opinionated and have certain philosophies on how to use them and as long as you stay within, you won't have any issues but if you try to break far out of the intended way to use you only make your own life more difficult.

Comment: Did you tried using vue.js instead? It has Angular-esque syntax within the templates, but is lightweight w/o controllers, just `new Vue{...}`ing the components. https://vuejs.org

Comment: @Tseng: That's not entirely true! I have used Angular 1 successfully and together with ASP.NET MVC and fills in the wholes when you need a rich user interaction. Angular is not meant for SPA only excuse me.

Comment: Like I said, if you fight it's SPA nature you fight against the way it's intended to be used. It suffers the same downsides ExtJS did suffer, just to a lower degree. ExtJS was great to make web application which had a Windows/Desktop Look & Feel, but the number of JS files required with each requests was so high that it would take seconds (>2) until the page renders and fetch all of it's dependencies, even when made modular. I've made a few angular (and in the past ExtJS) applications. The only way it makes sense to use both of them is in SPA

Comment: Because then you have one long load (~2 seconds) for base dependencies + currently used modules, then load the other modules dynamically on demand and components (which replaced controllers in old angular) communicate via ajax to a REST api w/o reloading current page in the browser. Blazing fast and the client sided navigation is instantaneous (if you don't count in the loading of the rest data)

Answer (score 2):

Feel like you have a whole application in one page returned by your MVC controller, and this page requires it's own api. However you can route to MVC framework back with any link. You don't have to use Angular router for it. The cost of switching between angular and non-angular worlds is very high. May be in the future releases of angular it will be cheaper. Anyway the concept of Multipage application is raw at the moment, and server-side rendering is not yet supported by the framework. It should come in the future versions.

#### Resources:

- [Angular 2 coming to Java, .Net and PHP - A multi-language Platform](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-coming-to-java-python-the-first-multi-language-full-stack-platform/)
- [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/)
- [Angular Universal - Getting Started](https://github.com/angular/universal#getting-started)

Comment: Well, there is kind of serverside-rendering support with ASP.NET Core though. https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices. Basically the Angular2 application runs on the server via node.js and ASP.NET Core will proxy to it for the first (if app was designed to have client side routing) and the once the dependencies are loaded continue with client side. w/o client side routing, will will just render the whole page on each request server-sided

Comment: @Tseng I'm not sure what you (or I) mean by server-side rendering but what they mean is "execute JavaScript on the server at runtime", but no any clue about client-server communication/protocols. If the loading of angular SPA page will be cheap (less than 1 sec) then it's what actually needed for MVC application. However MVC should be designed to seamlessly communicate with client to update only information that is required for the every single action (like SPA) with the possibility to interact with other SPAs hosted on the server.